# C# No mapping exists from object type System. Drawing. Bitmap to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying this **Church Management System** to submit for school but I keep getting this error and I don't know how to solve it.

[image]

I'm thinking its from the image but I don't know where exactly.

```
    private void btnBrowse_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declaring openfiledialog variable to help open files from pc
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        string img = "";

        //filtering files from pc (specific image type)
        ofd.Filter = "choose image (*.jpg;*.png;*.gif) |*.jpg; *.png; *.gif ";

        DialogResult dr = new DialogResult();
        dr = ofd.ShowDialog();

        if (dr.Equals(DialogResult.OK))
        {
            img = ofd.FileName;
            picMember.Image = System.Drawing.Bitmap.FromFile(img);
        }
    }
```

and from clicking the save  button, here's the code behind;

```
  private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        try
        {


            con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = Localhost; Initial Catalog = ChurchProject; Integrated Security = True");

            con.Open();

            // using commands to get member records when input
            cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into members(FullName,Gender,DateOfBirth,Auxiliary,Location,Address,"
                +"Telephone,WhatsApp,Email,[Membership Status],"
                + "[Marital Status],[Baptismal Status],Occupation,[Baptismal Year],[Admission Year],[Prev Church],"
                +"Prev_Position,ProfileImage)"
                + "values(@name,@sex,@dob,@aux,@loc,@address,@tel,@whatsapp,@email,@memberstat,@marital,@baptismStat,"
                +"@occup,@baptYear,@admission,@prev,@post,@image)", con);

            // assigning textboxes to database values
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", dtpDOB.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@aux", cmbAuxiliary.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image", picMember.Image);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", gender);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@loc", txtLocation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", txtAddress.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tel", txtTelNumber.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@whatsapp", txtWhatsApp.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@memberstat", cmbMembershipstat.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@marital", cmbMarital.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baptismStat", cmbBaptism.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@occup", txtOccupation.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@baptYear", dtpBaptism.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@admission", dtpAdmission.Value);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@prev", txtPrevChurch.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@post", txtPosition.Text);

            if (txtName.Text == "" && dtpDOB.Text == "" && dtpDOB.Text == "")
            {
                MessageBox.Show("All Fields Required!", "Membership Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
            else
            {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Records Saved Succesfully!", "Membership Status", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I'll be glad to receive help from you guys.

Comment: Store the byte array of the file, not the `Image` propery of the `PictureBox`

Comment: Okay, I'll do just that. Thanks